# Ansible - check if disk is mounted, if not format it

Tags: ansible

I am looking for help because I have trouble to get this thing done :

```
---
- name: Check if /data is already mounted
  debug: msg="The mount point exists"
  with_items: "{{ ansible_mounts }}"
  when: item.mount == "/data"
  register: check_mount

- name: Create /data directory if not exists
  ansible.builtin.file:
    path: /data
    state: directory
    owner: root
    group: root
    mode: '0751'

- name: Create a xfs filesystem on /dev/sda5
  community.general.filesystem:
    force: yes
    fstype: xfs
    dev: /dev/sda5
  when: not check_mount

- name: Get the /dev/sda5's UUID
  shell: blkid -s UUID -o value /dev/sda5
  register: blkid_out
  when: not check_mount

- name: Mount up device by UUID
  ansible.posix.mount:
    path: /data
    src: UUID={{ blkid_out.stdout }}
    fstype: xfs
    opts: defaults
    state: mounted
```

What am I trying to do :

- check if mountpoint exits and mounted then if not :
- create /data folder
- create the filesystem
- get the UUID
- mount the formatted disk on /data

do nothing if mountpoint exist.

The problem I have is I guess my check doesnt do anything but I do not know how to make it right with ansible_mount only and not with stat.

The first run do exactly what I want but I need to be able to run the playbook over and over and it shows me an error after the second run

```
    TASK [setup_disk : Create a xfs filesystem on /dev/sda5] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [blm-web-160]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": "/usr/sbin/mkfs.xfs -f /dev/sda5", "msg": "mkfs.xfs: /dev/sda5 contains a mounted filesystem\nUsage: mkfs.xfs\n/* blocksize */\t\t[-b size=num]\n/* metadata */\t\t[-m crc=0|1,finobt=0|1,uuid=xxx,rmapbt=0|1,reflink=0|1]\n/* data subvol */\t[-d agcount=n,agsize=n,file,name=xxx,size=num,\n\t\t\t    (sunit=value,swidth=value|su=num,sw=num|noalign),\n\t\t\t    sectsize=num\n/* force overwrite */\t[-f]\n/* inode size */\t[-i log=n|perblock=n|size=num,maxpct=n,attr=0|1|2,\n\t\t\t    projid32bit=0|1,sparse=0|1]\n/* no discard */\t[-K]\n/* log subvol */\t[-l agnum=n,internal,size=num,logdev=xxx,version=n\n\t\t\t    sunit=value|su=num,sectsize=num,lazy-count=0|1]\n/* label */\t\t[-L label (maximum 12 characters)]\n/* naming */\t\t[-n size=num,version=2|ci,ftype=0|1]\n/* no-op info only */\t[-N]\n/* prototype file */\t[-p fname]\n/* quiet */\t\t[-q]\n/* realtime subvol */\t[-r extsize=num,size=num,rtdev=xxx]\n/* sectorsize */\t[-s size=num]\n/* version */\t\t[-V]\n\t\t\tdevicename\n<devicename> is required unless -d name=xxx is given.\n<num> is xxx (bytes), xxxs (sectors), xxxb (fs blocks), xxxk (xxx KiB),\n      xxxm (xxx MiB), xxxg (xxx GiB), xxxt (xxx TiB) or xxxp (xxx PiB).\n<value> is xxx (512 byte blocks).", "rc": 1, "stderr": "mkfs.xfs: /dev/sda5 contains a mounted filesystem\nUsage: mkfs.xfs\n/* blocksize */\t\t[-b size=num]\n/* metadata */\t\t[-m crc=0|1,finobt=0|1,uuid=xxx,rmapbt=0|1,reflink=0|1]\n/* data subvol */\t[-d agcount=n,agsize=n,file,name=xxx,size=num,\n\t\t\t    (sunit=value,swidth=value|su=num,sw=num|noalign),\n\t\t\t    sectsize=num\n/* force overwrite */\t[-f]\n/* inode size */\t[-i log=n|perblock=n|size=num,maxpct=n,attr=0|1|2,\n\t\t\t    projid32bit=0|1,sparse=0|1]\n/* no discard */\t[-K]\n/* log subvol */\t[-l agnum=n,internal,size=num,logdev=xxx,version=n\n\t\t\t    sunit=value|su=num,sectsize=num,lazy-count=0|1]\n/* label */\t\t[-L label (maximum 12 characters)]\n/* naming */\t\t[-n size=num,version=2|ci,ftype=0|1]\n/* no-op info only */\t[-N]\n/* prototype file */\t[-p fname]\n/* quiet */\t\t[-q]\n/* realtime subvol */\t[-r extsize=num,size=num,rtdev=xxx]\n/* sectorsize */\t[-s size=num]\n/* version */\t\t[-V]\n\t\t\tdevicename\n<devicename> is required unless -d name=xxx is given.\n<num> is xxx (bytes), xxxs (sectors), xxxb (fs blocks), xxxk (xxx KiB),\n      xxxm (xxx MiB), xxxg (xxx GiB), xxxt (xxx TiB) or xxxp (xxx PiB).\n<value> is xxx (512 byte blocks).\n", "stderr_lines": ["mkfs.xfs: /dev/sda5 contains a mounted filesystem", "Usage: mkfs.xfs", "/* blocksize */\t\t[-b size=num]", "/* metadata */\t\t[-m crc=0|1,finobt=0|1,uuid=xxx,rmapbt=0|1,reflink=0|1]", "/* data subvol */\t[-d agcount=n,agsize=n,file,name=xxx,size=num,", "\t\t\t    (sunit=value,swidth=value|su=num,sw=num|noalign),", "\t\t\t    sectsize=num", "/* force overwrite */\t[-f]", "/* inode size */\t[-i log=n|perblock=n|size=num,maxpct=n,attr=0|1|2,", "\t\t\t    projid32bit=0|1,sparse=0|1]", "/* no discard */\t[-K]", "/* log subvol */\t[-l agnum=n,internal,size=num,logdev=xxx,version=n", "\t\t\t    sunit=value|su=num,sectsize=num,lazy-count=0|1]", "/* label */\t\t[-L label (maximum 12 characters)]", "/* naming */\t\t[-n size=num,version=2|ci,ftype=0|1]", "/* no-op info only */\t[-N]", "/* prototype file */\t[-p fname]", "/* quiet */\t\t[-q]", "/* realtime subvol */\t[-r extsize=num,size=num,rtdev=xxx]", "/* sectorsize */\t[-s size=num]", "/* version */\t\t[-V]", "\t\t\tdevicename", "<devicename> is required unless -d name=xxx is given.", "<num> is xxx (bytes), xxxs (sectors), xxxb (fs blocks), xxxk (xxx KiB),", "      xxxm (xxx MiB), xxxg (xxx GiB), xxxt (xxx TiB) or xxxp (xxx PiB).", "<value> is xxx (512 byte blocks)."], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
```

surely because it try to format somthing already in use.

It would be appreciated to have some tips from someone :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ansible modules are generally designed to be idempotent. Instead of doing extra checks to see if the filesystem already exists, you should use declarative tasks and the `filesystem` and `mount` modules will do the right thing.

```
- name: Create /data
  ansible.builtin.file:
    path: /data
    state: directory
    owner: root
    group: root
    mode: '0751'

- name: Create an xfs filesystem on /dev/sda5
  community.general.filesystem:
    fstype: xfs
    state: present
    dev: /dev/sda5

- name: Fetch the UUID of /dev/sda5
  command: blkid -s UUID -o value /dev/sda5
  changed_when: false
  register: blkid_out

- name: Mount /dev/sda5 by UUID
  ansible.posix.mount:
    path: /data
    src: UUID={{ blkid_out.stdout }}
    fstype: xfs
    opts: defaults
    state: mounted
```

First run:

```
ec2-user@pandora ~ $ ansible-playbook ~/test.yml

PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************

TASK [Create /data] ************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [Create an xfs filesystem on /dev/sda5] ***********************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [Fetch the UUID of /dev/sda5] *********************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Mount /dev/sda5 by UUID] *************************************************
changed: [localhost]

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=4    changed=3    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Second run:

```
ec2-user@pandora ~ $ ansible-playbook ~/test.yml

PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************

TASK [Create /data] ************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [Create an xfs filesystem on /dev/sda5] ***********************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Fetch the UUID of /dev/sda5] *********************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Mount /dev/sda5 by UUID] *************************************************
ok: [localhost]

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=4    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

If you *really need* to make it conditional you need to understand what the variables involved look like.

```
- name: Check if /data is already mounted
  debug: msg="The mount point exists"
  with_items: "{{ ansible_mounts }}"
  when: item.mount == "/data"
  register: check_mount
```

As you'll see if you debug it, the task result in `check_mount` contains the results for every loop item, so `check_mount` itself is always a truthy value. To see whether it ran anything, you need to use `when: check_mount is not skipped`, not `when: check_mount`.

However, this is not a good pattern for conditionals, because it requires an extra task with potentially a lot of looping output. It's better to directly check for the condition you want in your `when` statement.

```
- when: ansible_facts.mounts | selectattr('mount', '==', '/data') | length == 0
  block:
    - name: Create an xfs filesystem on /dev/sda5
      community.general.filesystem:
        state: present
        fstype: xfs
        dev: /dev/sda5

    - name: Fetch the UUID of /dev/sda5
      command: blkid -s UUID -o value /dev/sda5
      changed_when: false
      register: blkid_out

    - name: Mount /dev/sda5 by UUID
      ansible.posix.mount:
        path: /data
        src: UUID={{ blkid_out.stdout }}
        fstype: xfs
        opts: defaults
        state: mounted
```

Comment: thank you so much @flowerysong for your detailed explanations, I understand know where I failed, it was in part because I do not handle ansible well, thanks you again it began to be hard for me without help, if you have any ressources beside the official documentation to learn ansible by example I take :)