# Ansible: How to check if device is formatted and if not format it to 'ext4'?

Tags: ansible

As a preparation for the mount task, all attached volumes that are not yet formatted and part of a list (any format is sufficient) should be formatted to `ext4`. All volumes of that list are then mounted afterwards.

**Volume List**

I hold a list containing dictionaries of the kind `{name: tomountto, device: nameofattacheddevice}`. I would like to only go over the devices within the list and mount every device that only contains one partition.

**Base Idea**

```yaml
- when: volumes is defined
  block:
    - name: Creates directory
      file:
        path: "{{ item.name }}"
        state: directory

    # Code To Format Volumes If Not Formatted

    - name: Mount disks
      mount:
        path: "{{ item.name }}"
        src: "{{ item.device }}"
        state: mounted
  with_items:
    - volumes
```

**Format Volumes If Not Formatted**

I found this here, [Ansible - check if disk is mounted, if not format it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69947414/ansible-check-if-disk-is-mounted-if-not-format-it) but it is not really what I am looking for.

Another idea I found to check whether a disk is formatted is to use `stat` with

```yaml
when: not (disk_info.stat.exists and disk_info.stat.size > 0)
```

and then use `filesystem` to format the disk.

However, I am wondering whether there is a more native solution for my issue.

**Using force false**

```yaml
- name: Make sure disks are available
  filesystem:
    fstype: ext4
    dev: "{{item.device}}"
    force: false
    state: present
  ignore_errors: true
  when: volumes is defined
  with_items:
    - "{{ volumes }}"

- name: Create mount folders if it doesn't exist
  ansible.builtin.file:
    path: "/{{item.name}}"
    state: directory
    mode: '0755'
  with_items:
    - "{{ volumes }}"

- name: Mount disks
  mount:
    path: "{{ item.name }}"
    src: "{{ item.device }}"
    fstype: ext4
    state: mounted
  with_items:
    - "{{ volumes }}"
  when: volumes is defined
```

But this solution doesn't always work, because sometimes the device has more than one partition, but item.device only holds the name of the device not necessarily of the partition I would like to mount. For example:

```
vdc     vfat
└─vdc1  vfat
```

would fail, but

```
vdc     ext4
```

would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Check if device is formatted - if not format it to `ext4`*

I am not fully sure if there is an fact in [`ansible_facts.ansible_devices`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html#ansible-facts) for an empty unformatted block device available, therefore you may have a look into the following minimal example.

```yaml
- name: Find the block device (disk) without a filesystem
  shell:
    cmd: "lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE -dsn | grep -v '[0-9]' | tr -d ' '"
    warn: false
  changed_when: false
  check_mode: false
  register: disk

- name: Show finding
  debug: 
    msg: "{{ disk.stdout }}"

- name: "Make sure disk is available with ext4"
  filesystem:
    fstype: ext4
    dev: "/dev/{{ disk.stdout }}"
  when: disk.stdout | length > 0
```

**Credits To**

- [How to capture all disks that don’t have a file system](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/412517/266568)
- [Finding all storage devices attached to a Linux machine](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49786/)

Comment: I just want to format those elements that are part of an input list. Also, I think that `disk.stdout` needs to be cleaned before putting it into `filesystem`. Using `filesystem` I created a somewhat working solution. I've added this attempt as information.